# Use a variable in foreach

Tags: foreach, loops, pgfmath, variable

I am trying to use a variable in my foreach loop. It would make things a lot easier, because i only need to change one value and multiple loops are affected.

Something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro\end{2}

    \foreach \x in {0,...,\end}{
        %do something
    }


    \foreach \x in {1,...,\end}{
        %do something
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that when using this im getting lots of errors that aren't related to this tikZ image. There mostly `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` Like something broke.

Thanks a lot in advantage

Comment: @SebGlav I have added my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redefining `\end` at the same grouping level as the `\end{tikzpicture}` instruction. So when TeX sees `\end{tikzpicture}` it will obey your redefinition and replace it with

```
2.0{tikzpicture}
```

Can you see why your choice isn't really good?

Use a different name, there's plenty of them, for instance `\END`. But it should really be

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\END}{2}
```

otherwise you will get `2.0` and the loop would use floating point numbers.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\END{2}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,\END}{
       \draw(\x,1)--(\x,0);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it now works like a charm. I was very confused at the beginning but it all makes sense now